# From Liferay's 'Asset Publisher'... view only those documents from a specific folder

Tags: liferay

Via the 'Asset Publisher', Is there a way through the 'configuration' of the portlet to view only those documents located in a specific folder?

That is, a filter that shows only the documents in Folder 'X', for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without custom development.

We had a similar requirement, and what we did was to implement a FolderModelListener that added a category to each document in a folder with the name of the folder as category name. Each time a document is uploaded into the folder, it receives this category.

This allowed us to configure the Asset Publisher using normal categories.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple workaround w/o the need of coding is to tag those web contents. Then set a filter to this tag in the asset publisher's display settings. 
Think about the semantic web contents as a pool of entries which are tagged by meaning.